# File.createNewFile is ignored

Tags: android, file, android-studio

I'm currently having this issue "File.creteNewFile() is ignore".
Okay, when a picture been taken, the picture will be view in image switcher, so when I took a photo and save it, it didn't appear in the image switcher after I took another photo then the previous picture will appear in the image switcher. 
For example, when I took a picture of James and save it, it didn't appear in image switcher, when I took a picture of Simon then James picture appear in the Image Switcher but Simon didn't, and the next picture taken then Simon picture will appear in the Image switcher.

```
public void Save() {
    try {
        File f = new File(mPath + "faces.txt");
        f.createNewFile();   <-- this is where the method is ignored
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        Iterator<label> Ilabel = thelist.iterator();
        while (Ilabel.hasNext()) {
            label l = Ilabel.next();
            bw.write(l.thelabel + "," + l.num);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage() + " " + e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm new with android but I hope you guys could help me :D

Cheers,
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 4):

Inspection `createNewFile` is saying "Result of File.createNewFile() is ignored" because the boolean result is not assigned to any variable, so it's ignored

If you do

`boolean sucess = file.createNewFile()` the message disappear :)

Bonus, from docs:

> Returns true if the named file does not exist and was successfully
>   created, false if the named file already exists

Answer (score 0):

dont use createNewFile() methos
create your file using this method:

```
public void Save(){
            try
            {
                File root = new File(mPath);
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                File gpxfile = new File(root, "faces.txt");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                writer.append(sBody);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                importError = e.getMessage();
                iError();
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi saber :D what is sBody

Comment: your data that you want write in file like json or text or enything else

Answer (score -1):

You're ending the file's path in .txt, but it's an image isn't it? I don't know if this is causing your problem or not, but it should probably be fixed.